# Comparing 2 Different Tables to One Another - SQL Query

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My SQL query is returning incorrect results when trying to compare 2 different tables to one another to verify that each individual case is equal to one another.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 b ON a.column1 = b.column1 
   AND a.column2 = b.column2
   AND a.column3 = b.column3
WHERE (a.date = '2021-01-01') OR (b.date = '2021-01-01') AND
(a.column4 != b.column4 OR (a.column4 IS NULL AND b.column4 IS NOT NULL) OR (a.column4 IS NOT NULL AND b.column4 IS NULL));
```

The primary key is composed of 3 columns with `column2` and `column3` able to hold null values. Adding the `b.date` clause doubles my results. I was aiming to only return results that are not equal to eachother in a row to row comparison.

Comment: The `AND` operator has higher priority than the `OR` operator so `x OR y AND z` is evaluated as `x OR (y AND z)` when you probably want to use brackets around the `OR` operator to change the precedence so it is evaluated as `(x OR y) AND z`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parenthesis on your WHERE (1st) part.  Try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 b ON a.column1 = b.column1 
   AND a.column2 = b.column2
   AND a.column3 = b.column3
WHERE ((a.date = '2021-01-01') OR (b.date = '2021-01-01')) AND
(a.column4 != b.column4 OR (a.column4 IS NULL AND b.column4 IS NOT NULL) OR (a.column4 IS NOT NULL AND b.column4 IS NULL));
```

Comment: Reduced the number of rows that were returned but are still incorrect. I am verifying by manually checking one of the cases returned and they hold the same exact values.

Comment: Can you select one sample row which is giving the difference and use NVL to see if any columns are having Null value.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing nullable columns could be achieved by using [IS DISTINCT FROM](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/is-distinct-from) predicate:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 b 
  ON a.column1 = b.column1 
   AND a.column2 = b.column2
   AND a.column3 = b.column3
WHERE '2021-01-01'::DATE IN (a.date, b.date)
  AND a.column4 IS DISTINCT FROM b.column4;
```